# Can Excel Pivot Tables delimit data and perform calculations on the data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a document for work to track a lot of information and provide feedback based on the inputs. I have nearly everything I need complete, except the results that occur. I have multiple categories that a large number of combinations can occur (number can be from 1-100, with a selection of about 40 different items, and any combination of this total so there is very little consistency with inputs), so I'm trying to keep input for each category in a single column. Unfortunately, I do not have PowerQuery available.

A simplified example of the input is:
[image: Table Input Data]

I'd like the Pivot to delimit the data, separate by category and subsequently equipment/vehicle type and sum the values associated.

[image: Resulting Pivot Output]

Edit: I apologize, I didn't include this in the original.  The full table that I use is Columns A-AC, and Rows 1-10,000.  This data is in columns S-U.

Answer (score 0):

**NO.**

Pivot table cannot do that. You need to process your data before feeding it to the pivot table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; is there a way to automatically delimit the data without using power query?  I understand the answer below, but the full table that I use is Columns A-AC, and Rows 1-10,000.  This data is in columns S-U.

Comment: "No" in my answer means "no".

Comment: " I understand the answer below, but the full table that I use is Columns A-AC, and Rows 1-10,000. This data is in columns S-U" - so what is the main problem with that answer? Using power query or referring to the wrong range?

Comment: No issue; I can adjust where the cells are, but I would like to automate the delimiting process, if possible, so that when I add the information to those columns, it automatically delimits, even if I have to do it on another sheet.

Comment: OK. Still no. Spliting cell content into multiple cells is not an easy task with formulas, and unfortunately you can't avoid it. For automation you need to use either power query or macros.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Power Query to get you result.

1. Go to Data- From Table/Range- enter Query Editor:

[image]

2. Go to Transform- Unpivot all columns in Query Editor:

[image]

3. Go to Home- select Value Column- select Spilt column by Delimiter- Select Custom Delimiter and enter ", "- select Advanced option and check Spilt into Row:

[image]

4. Select Value Column- select Spilt column by Delimiter- Select Space Delimiter:

[image]

5. Close and load as a PivotTable:

[image]

6. If you change the data source the PivotTable will upload automatically:

[image]

Comment: "Unfortunately, I do not have PowerQuery available"

Comment: I apologize, I didn't include this in the original.  The full table that I use is Columns A-AC, and Rows 1-10,000.  This data is in columns S-U.

Comment: Sorry... :( I read your question unclearly.

Comment: Not a problem, I appreciate the response.